# Nodejs lookup of known bluetooth device

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, bluetooth

Is it possible to perform a lookup of a Bluetooth device given its address in a Nodejs script?

There are a few packages out there, the main one being Noble. However, they all focus around scanning, and not looking up a known address (as far as i can tell anyway!).

What i want to achieve, is to look up a known address, to see if the device can be found.
Much like PyBluez does for Python:
`bluetooth.lookup_name('CC:20:E8:8F:3A:1D', timeout=5)`

In Python, this can find the device even if it is undiscoverable, unlike a typical inquiry scan would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem and just found the btwatch lib, but it isn't working for me on the latest raspbian. But the source is just calling l2ping and looking for a string that I'm guessing no longer prints on success, so the modified code below works instead, similar to the lookup_name method, once you have l2ping installed (I think npm bluetooth or pybluez has it)

```
var Spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function detectMacAddress(macAddress, callback)
{
    //var macAddress = '72:44:56:05:79:A0';
    var ls = Spawn('l2ping', ['-c', '1', '-t', '5', macAddress]);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("Found device in Range! " + macAddress);
        callback(true);
    });

    ls.on('close', function () {
        console.log("Could not find: " + macAddress);
        callback(false);
    });
}
```

Or, a synchronous way,

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

function detectMacAddressSync(macAddress)
{
    var cmd = 'l2ping -c 1 -t 5 ' + macAddress;
    try
    {
        var output = execSync(cmd );
        console.log("output : "+ output );
        return true;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("caught: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! amazing! This is exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood the problem you want to connect to the device using address. Then, I would suggest using [node-bluetooth-serial-port](https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port).

```
var btSerial = new (require('bluetooth-serialport')).BluetoothSerialPort();

btSerial.on('found', function(address, name) {
    btSerial.findSerialPortChannel(address, function(channel) {
        btSerial.connect(address, channel, function() {
        console.log('connected');

        btSerial.write(new Buffer('my data', 'utf-8'), function(err, bytesWritten) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });

        btSerial.on('data', function(buffer) {
            console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8'));
        });
    }, function () {
        console.log('cannot connect');
    });

    // close the connection when you're ready
    btSerial.close();
}, function() {
    console.log('found nothing');
});
});
```

**BluetoothSerialPort.findSerialPortChannel(address, callback[, errorCallback])**

Checks if a device has a serial port service running and if it is found it passes the channel id to use for the RFCOMM connection.

callback(channel) - called when finished looking for a serial port on the device.
errorCallback - called the search finished but no serial port channel was found on the device. Connects to a remote bluetooth device.

bluetoothAddress - the address of the remote Bluetooth device.

channel - the channel to connect to.
[successCallback] - called when a connection has been established.
[errorCallback(err)] - called when the connection attempt results in an error. The parameter is an Error object.

Comment: HI rresol, I have just done some playing around with this. It doesn't seem to work in the same way as the Python example. It seems that because the device i am testing for does not broadcast any channels, `BluetoothSerialPort.findSerialPortChannel` always fails unless its discoverable. At this stage, i am aiming to simply check if the device is present. Im not sure of the inner workings of any of these, but it seems Pythons `.lookup_name` simply looks for the device, but the bluetooth-serialport library is looking for the device **and** for it to have available channels. if that make sense?